# How to take values from 2 Array and make it into 1 value in a new array?

Tags: arrays, merge

i have 2 arrays:
"interfaceTitles" with the values "USB ports", "digital inputs", "RS232, ...
"interfaceAmounts" with the values "3", "20", "1", ...

I need a merged Array with combined values. So the new array should have the following values:
"3 USB ports", "20 digital inputs" ...

So its not just concating, its fusionating :D

`interfacesAdded = interfaceAmounts && interfaceTitles` doesn't work

`interfacesAdded = interfaceAmounts + interfaceTitles` makes it into an string

"interfacesAdded" is declared as `const interfacesAdded: any = ...`

what can I do for this, Search function didn't help me, sorry im kinda unexperienced :(

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below uses the `map` function to loop over the `interfaceTitles` list, and return a new list where the elements are the corresponding elements from the two lists joined by a space.

```
const result = interfaceTitles.map((_, i) => {
    return interfaceAmounts[i] + " " + interfaceTitles[i];
});
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think  you could add the language you are using to help better answer,
the logic will be the same in different language, i'm doing it in js.
Admitting the string you want to concat are in the same position of the 2 arrays:

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];
const array2 = ['a','b','c','d'];
// pass a function to map
// care in js we can use the + to concat string
// map will iterate over each element of array1
// x will be the current element of array1
// index will be the index of the current element,
// used to get the corresponding element in array2
const map1 = array1.map((x,index) => x+array2[index]);

console.log(map1);
// expected output: > Array ["1a", "4b", "9c", "16d"]
```